# One to many relationship saving integer into database laravel

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

I am having some trouble saving the FamilyAge using a one to many relationship. As you can see at the last row, I tried to save 3 different person but for the family age, there is only 1 value appearing instead of 3.  Please point out mistake, thanks in advance and also sorry for the weird words that I saved in the database, I just type in randomly

[image]

Personal_info has many family family_info (one to many relationship)

family_info controller:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{

  $personal_info = Session::get('data');

  $data7 = array();
  $data7['NameOfFamily'] = implode(' , ', $request->NameOfFamily);
  $data7['Relationship'] = implode(' , ', $request->Relationship);
  $data7['FamilyAge'] = implode(' , ', $request->FamilyAge);
  $family_info = new family_info;
  $family_info = family_info::create($data7);
  $family_info->personal_infos()->associate($personal_info);
  $family_info->save();

}
```

personal_info controller:

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
  $data = array();
  $data[Name] = $request->Name;
  $data['Email'] = $request->Email;
  $personal_info = personal_info::create($data);
  $personal_info->push();
  Session::put('data', $personal_info);
}
```

personal_info model:

```
class personal_info extends Eloquent
{
  protected $fillable = array('Name', 'Email');
  protected $table = 'personal_infos';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  public function family-infos() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\family_info,'user_id');
 }
```

family info model

```
protected $fillable =     
  array('NameOfFamily','Relationship','FamilyAge','user_id');

public function personal_infos() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\personal_info', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: is that "language model" or family_info model?

Comment: It family_info model, sorry type the wrong model, just changed it @Harshakj89

Comment: Having difficulties understanding your first paragraph. Try to make it  more clear. and if you have inserted data your table, provide a screenshot of that.

Comment: What database are you using? How is your table defined? I don't understand the first paragraph either.

Comment: Hi guys, I have updated my question, could you take a look again, so sorry for my poor english

Comment: Is it because in my database I am saving FamilyAge as an integer? So it can only take in 1 value and not mutiple